# Buck Converter Small-Signal Control Model

Tags: power-electronics

[image]

[image]

Extract from Power Management Techniques for Integrated Circuits.

The author presents a small-signal model for a voltage-mode buck converter in the figure. He then creates an expression for the small-signal Vout voltage due to these small signal disturbance sources shown in the figure. The expression is  Eq 3.22

**I don't understand the coefficients he is multiplying the disturbance sources by? Can someone explain how derived them?** I think it's something from feedback theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of a simpler block to represent your closed-loop system as I shown in my [APEC 2012](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202012.pdf) seminar:

[image]

If you go through the simple algebra and rearrange the formula, you end up with an expression similar to what is given in the text you refer to. The term \$S=\frac{1}{1+T(s)}\$ is called *the sensitivity* function and defines how vigorously a closed-loop system rejects a perturbation. You can add the input \$V_{in}\$, temperature or any other adjacent input and you will see that these are also rejected by the same amount.

It means that when the loop gain is high, well before the crossover frequency, the system rejects these perturbations quite well. For instance, if there is a high gain at 100 Hz, then the rectified ripple in an ac-dc converter is likely to be well weakened when it appears on the output. For stability reasons, you naturally force an open-loop gain \$T\$ reduction and, eventually, it becomes equal to 1 at the crossover frequency \$f_c\$. So, I often use the simple adage *no gain, no feedback* meaning that, before crossover, the system operates in ac closed-loop conditions while, beyond crossover, the system operates in ac open loop and does what it can to reject the perturbation. You will find comprehensive modeling details about the buck converter in my last [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1949267512) on transfer functions of switching converters.